# Erasing encryption (LUKS) keys before suspend-to-RAM?

Tags: linux, luks

I recently had been wondering if there is a way to erase my LUKS keys from RAM before I suspend my device (usually a laptop) to S3 mode. I am interested in a solution that would work for my `/` partition. The way I imagine this, I'd like my system to ask me for password again when I resume it.

If such a solution does not exist, I'm wondering if a VM-based one would work. Before suspend, the VM would also be suspended (on in some other way paused), a debugger would look for the LUKS private key, save it to some secure location, wipe all its occurrences from RAM and on power resumption, decrypt the secret using the user's password and restore it to all saved offsets. The same could probably be done with GPG/SSH/Bitcoin keys. Would this be a secure approach? If not, why?

Comment: I think there actually _are_ some hypervisor-based academic solutions.

Answer (score 4):

The solution is called "Hibernate" or suspend to disk.

By design, suspend to RAM wakes instantly, and is intended more as a power-saving mode than a version of "switched off".

Software can get notifications that suspend-to-ram is about to occur, and things like Password Safe programs should - and typically do - automatically clear their keys. You could readily alter e.g. SSH clients to do the same, if they don't already.

However disk encryption programmes cannot necessarily do this, as files open on those disks may need to be accessed as part of the resume process.

Answer (score 4):

**Non-system partition**

For partitions *other* than the system partition you can use the following systemd unit:

```
[Unit]
Description=Wipe Keys before <target>
After=<target>

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/path/to/wipe

[Install]
WantedBy=<target>
```

`<target>` is the corresponding target of your desired mode. From the [systemd-suspend.service Manpage](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-suspend.service.html):
`suspend.target`, `hibernate.target`, or `hybrid-sleep.target`

And the `wipe` script:

```
dmsetup suspend "$name"
dmsetup message "$name" 0 key wipe
```

or if you use LUKS

```
cryptsetup luksSuspend <name>
```

After you resume your system your need to issue:

```
dmsetup message "$name" 0 key set  "$key"
dmsetup resume  "$name"
```

or

```
cryptsetup luksResume <name>
```

**Virtual Machine**

If you put your whole virtual machine on an encrypted disk of the host, you can use the same approach, but you need to stop the guest with "Save the system state", and ensure, that this state is also saved on the encrypted disk. Wou would prepend something like the following commands to your `wipe` script:

```
VBoxManage controlvm "$vboxname" savestate
```

and to resume

```
VBoxManage controlvm "$vboxname" resume
```

Keep in mind that failing to actually stop the guest would *not* expose your encryption keys. It would only leave the RAM of the guest unencrypted in your RAM or swap.

**Full system encryption**

There is a solution for Hibernation (saving RAM to the drive) with whole system encryption. Basically you also have to encrypt your swap. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/201868/83120) and [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Swap_Encryption#With_suspend-to-disk_support) This does not help you when suspending to RAM.